# CALayer clipping

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation, calayer, cagradientlayer

I have a CALayer configured as follows:

```
private func setup() {

    guard let theLayer = self.layer as? CAGradientLayer else {
        return;
    }


    theLayer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor] 
    theLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    theLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    theLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
    theLayer.frame = self.bounds

}
```

I want to clip it to a rect based on user input value (called 'value' in code below). How do I do it?

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rect.width, height: rect.height * (1-value))

   // How to clip or mask self.layer to above frame? 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Embed the layer in a container layer that has appropriate `frame` and set its `masksToBounds` property to `true`.